# c++ Performance Of And Operator With Example

Tags: c++

I was wondering if the && operator works in a cascading manor. Compare the following implementations of a rectangle collision check.

```
inline bool RectInRect(RECT one,RECT two){
    if(one.left < two.right)
    if(one.right > two.left)
    if(one.top < two.bottom)
    if(one.bottom > two.top)
    return true;
    return false;
}


inline bool RectInRect(RECT one,RECT two){
        return (one.left < two.right && one.right > two.left &&
            one.top < two.bottom && one.bottom > two.top);
}
```

Are these both the same or will the top one operate faster?

Comment: [**A cascading manor**](http://www.wright-house.com/frank-lloyd-wright/fallingwater-pictures/F1SW-fallingwater-in-fall.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the second version essentially boils down to the first. The relevant property of the operator is that it’s [**short-circuited**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation): the second operand is only evaluated if necessary, that is, if the first operand evaluates to `true`. Otherwise, the whole expression will *always* evaluate to `false` so there’s no need to look at the second operand.

This behaviour is guaranteed and is analogous, but the other way round, for `||` / `or`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that the version on the top be faster then the one below. Also for me the statement below is way clearer so my advice is - better use the second version.

Comment: If the and operators require completion of the entire statement then the top one will be faster.

Comment: No the operator is short-circuted - on the first failed condition the whole statement becomes false. So all the conditions are checked by turns left to right and the first one that fails renderes the statement to be false, or true is returned if all the conditions are true.